# How to recover forgotten SSH password in OctoPi?

Tags: octopi

I have forgotten my OctoPi SSH password. Now I want to install X server and browser for touch UI. How can I recover that password without deleting it all to the ground and reinstalling it?

Comment: Adding as a self-answer because I have spent way to much time trying to look it up.

Comment: If you waited a few hours more I could answer it for you, I've had the same issues before and documented it in my personal notes.

Answer (score 1):

[foosel](https://community.octoprint.org/u/foosel), Project Leader of OctoPrint, helpfully provided a [solution just for us](https://community.octoprint.org/t/forgotten-username-and-password-to-ssh-into-pi/8839/7):

Turn off the Raspberry Pi and then:

> Take the SD card out, put it in a card reader. Create a file octopi-password.txt on it, containing a new password as it's only line. Unmount, boot, login with the new password.

You can do it in Windows, because you need to put it on the Boot partition, the only one that mounts.

Comment: Now keep in mind that this is a potential security issue: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19087/how-to-encrypt-wifi-password-in-octopi-wifi-config-file